# Command not found

Tags: zsh, jhipster, macos-sierra, oh-my-zsh

I want use oh-my-zsh jhipster plugin. I followed Jhipster guidelines using

> http://www.jhipster.tech/oh-my-zsh/

After setting up everything, whenever i try to use command jh, it doesn't work. I get response

```
zsh: command not found
```

I'm not familiar with shell scripting language. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to:

- install zsh
- install oh-my-zsh
- configure your default shell to use zsh -> it is important
- install jhipster-oh-my-zsh-plugin

Here the commands we do for our jhipster-devbox (on Ubuntu):

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox/blob/master/scripts/setup.sh#L100-L112

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed zsh?

I am not familiar with MAC, but it should be something like:

```
brew install zsh zsh-completions
```

here some more in-deep instructions:

http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/iTerm/zsh.html

Comment: Yeah I installed. When I check version, it is there.